# One Hot Encoding of ranges of data vs. leaving data as is for Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, categorical-encoding, splines, binning

Recently whilst doing an assignment using the PIMA Diabetes set I ran Logistic Regression using, amongst others:

- the age predictor as is
- segmented the age into ranges and applied OHE (with and without scaling).

There was a slight increase in some trained and validates models when using OHE.

My question is: why would OHE be better than the (scaled) age predictor? I cannot find a suitable explanation.

Comment: It is probably an artifact of the data set and the variables you used. Fine-grained continuous variables will always be better than OHE dummies -- particularly for updating the weights.

Comment: OK, so why is it that many examples and courses attempt to do this then? I agree with you. @JohnStud

Comment: Not sure. It makes little theoretical sense, on those grounds alone, to "throw out" continuous data in exchange for a dummy. Modeling decisions should always be justified, as we can predict most data sets that we have by just generating enough random Xs.

Comment: @JohnStud  but you are not giving an answer

Comment: That's right, I am giving you a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the relationship between the predictor and the target is not linear in log-odds, then binning and one-hot-encoding may perform better because the model gets to learn unrelated weights for each bin.  This will be particularly noticeable if the true relationship is not monotonic.  There will be a tradeoff in the size/number of bins as well: too small and the bins will make it easy to overfit, but too few and you lose too much of the continuous information.

Probably a better approach is to fit a spline, which accounts for the nonlinearity and does not throw away the information of the continuous predictor.  There are several answers/comments here on the downsides of binning, e.g. [What is the benefit of breaking up a continuous predictor variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/232706) ; see related/linked questions and the tag [binning](/questions/tagged/binning) for more.